# How to use Google Blogger Lambda Operators

Tags: lambda, blogger

Google Blogger has implemented a new set of Lambda expression operators for its template language. See: https://blogger.googleblog.com/2016/05/more-custom-template-flexibility.html and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/l3phi8bscGY .

The example code given (the b:if/ amended) is:

```
<!-- Show a Flower image if the post has the label flower -->
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (l => l.name == "Flower")'>
  <img src=’/img/flower.jpg’ />
</b:if>
```

I can't figure out how to get this to work in a template. Would someone please provide some working code I could drop in to a template and see it working.

UPDATE:
This seems to work. But how, or can I, remove the loop?

```
<b:section class='Test1' id='Test1' maxwidgets='' showaddelement='no'>
    <b:widget id='Blog2' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog' version='1' visible='true'>
        <b:includable id='main'>

            <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
                <h1>Post found</h1>

                <b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label  => label.name == "flower")'>
                    <h1>Flower!</h1>
                </b:if>

            </b:loop>
        </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

For example, if I remove the loop, and replace it with :

```
<b:if cond='data:posts any (p  => p.title  != "bob")'>                  
    <h1>Post found</h1>           
</b:if>>
```

Only one post is found, when I have several posts none of which are titled bob! I have tried switching the lambda operator from any to filter with no change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The solution to my problem**

Stupid of me, if I expect to be able to use a loop I need to specify a loop:

```
<b:loop values='data:posts filter (p  => p.id  != 0)'  var='post'>                    
  <h1>Post found: <data:post.title/></h1>           
</b:loop>
```

**How to use Blogger Lambda Operators**

For those coming here trying to find help I recommend the following article which explains how to use Lambda expressions quite comprehensively: http://www.bloggerever.com/2016/05/what-are-exactly-bloggers-lambda.html and is based on https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/l3phi8bscGY.

In essence there are 7 Lambda operators

- any
- all
- none
- count
- filter
- map
- first

Each of which can be used either inside an if or loop conditional statement. Some untested sample code follows to help get you started.

The **any** operator returns true if any items in the Lambda return true, so for example, the following code would return true if a post had a label labela or labelb associated with it:

```
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels any
               (l  => l.name in {"labela","labelb"})'>
      ...Code here...
</b:if>
```

**all** would return true if it had both labela and labelb associated with it:

```
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels all  
               (l  => l.name not in {"labela","labelb"})'>
      ...Code here...
</b:if>
```

**none** would return true if it had neither labela and labelb associated with it:

```
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels all  
               (l  => l.name not in {"labela","labelb"})'>
      ...Code here...
</b:if>
```

**count** would return 0, 1 or 2 depending on whether a post had neither labela or labelb associated with it, or just labela or both labela and labelb

```
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels count
               (l  => l.name not in {"labela","labelb"})'>
      ...Code here...
</b:if>
```

**filter** will return an array and requires a loop. The example below would print out the title of each post unless it had an id of 0 (which i don't is possible!)

```
<b:loop values='data:posts filter (p  => p.id  != 0)'  var='post'>                    
    <h1>Post found: <data:post.title/></h1>           
</b:loop>
```

**first** like filter, but will return the first match only.

```
<b:loop values='data:posts first(p  => p.timestamp  == "4.2.09")'  var='post'>                    
    <h1>Post found: <data:post.title/></h1>           
</b:loop>
```

**map** returns an array set containing each result from the Lambda. The code below would display labels in a h1 tag with >> prepended.

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels map (l=> ">>" + l.name)' var='label'>
     <h1><data:label/></h1>
</b:loop>
```

**A final note:** the article linked to suggests the Lambda's may only be applied to post, label and comment elements. It certainly works with the first two but I haven't tried it with comments.

Comment: Thanks this helps me a lot. :D

Comment: It works for comments too, for example, here I use the lambda expression to detect whether a comment has children or not: http://www.dte.web.id/2018/05/mengetahui-jumlah-komentar-balasan.html