# Run a javascript on regex pattern match url (Blogger)

Tags: javascript, regex, url, blogger

I'm trying to load a javascript on several pages but I only on pages which the url matches with a specific pattern.

The following code works for specific pages but it doesn't accept any wildcard or regex

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;https://mywebsite.com/yyyy/mm/article.html&quot;'>
<script src='https://javascritp.js'/>
</b:if>
```

The closest thing I found is described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48432/add-javascript-to-multiple-specific-urls) but since my website is running on Blogger I don't know how to use that code.

Any suggestion or help please?

Answer (score 0):

Blogger conditional statements don't provide pattern matching capability. It would be easier to implement what you require via JavaScript directly in the Blogger template -

An example code would look like -

```
if(window.location.href.match(/Regex-Condition/){
    var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    script.src = 'URL-Of-The-Script-You-Want-To-Load';script.async=true;
    var insertScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; insertScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, insertScript);
}
```

Other than this, you can also take a look at Lambda expressions (Refer to [How to use Google Blogger Lambda Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436554/how-to-use-google-blogger-lambda-operators) )

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank you for your feedback! While I was waiting for some reply I realized I've to use JavaScript as you said.

I was testing this code but it looks something is wrong:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var pattern = new RegExp(&#39;mywebsite\.com\/(200[8-9]|201[0-6])\/&#39;);
if (pattern.test(document.location.href)) {

}

</script>
```

I've two main concerns:

- if the regex is correct
- between the brackets I've to execute some code which includes Blogger conditional statements, div and plain JavaScript. Does this code need some special attention?

Thanks